# Lambda variable capture in loop - what happens here?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I am trying to get  my head around, what happens here ? What sort of code does the compiler produce?

```
public static void vc()
{
    var listActions = new List<Action>();

    foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
    {
        listActions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(i));
    }

    foreach (Action action in listActions)
    {
        action();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
  vc();
}
```

*output:* 
10
10
.. 
10

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438307/detailed-explanation-of-variable-capture-in-closures), a new instance of ActionHelper would be created for every iteration. So in that case, I would assume it should print 1..10.
Can someone give me some pseudo code of what the compiler is doing here ?

Thanks.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: It seems that it is no longer an issue with VS2013 and .NET 4.5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this line

```
 listActions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

the variable `i`, is captured, or if you wish, created a **pointer** to the memory location of that variable. That means that **every** delegate got a *pointer* to that memory location. After this loop execution:

```
foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
{
    listActions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(i));
}
```

for obvious reasons `i` is `10`, so the memory content that all pointers present in `Action`(s) are pointing, becomes 10.

In other words, `i` is captured.

By the way, should note, that according to Eric Lippert, this "strange" behaviour would be  **resolved** in `C# 5.0`.

So in the `C# 5.0` your program would print *as expected*:

```
1,2,3,4,5...10
```

EDIT:

Can not find Eric Lippert's post on subject, but here is another one:

[Closure in a Loop Revisited](http://deploytonenyures.blogspot.it/2012/05/closure-in-loop-revisited-c-50.html)

Comment: I linked it in my answer, but since this one will likely end up at the top of the votes list: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: C# 5.0 was released on August 2012 and it's included in Visual Studio 2012, so technically it's already "fixed".

Comment: @PaoloMoretti: or better wait for service pack 1 ? :)

Answer (score 9):

> What sort of code does the compiler produce ?

It sounds like you expect this:

```
foreach (int temp in Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
{
    int i = temp;
    listActions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(i));
}
```

That uses a *different* varaible for each iteration, and so the value of the variable at the time the lambda is created will be captured. In fact, you could use this exact code and get the result you want.

But what the compiler actually does is something closer to this:

```
int i;
foreach (i in Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
{
    listActions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(i));
}
```

This makes it clear that you are capturing the *same* variable on each iteration. When you later go and actually execute that code, they all refer to the *same* value that has already be incremented up to 10.

This is **not** a bug in the compiler or runtime... it was a conscious decision on the part of the language design team. However, due to confusion about how this works, they have reversed that decision and [decided to risk a breaking change to make it work more like you expect for C# 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

Comment: I think for new programmers one other common misconception is not that the foreach generates different variables, but that lambdas close over values rather than variables.

Comment: @Servy - for reference types, it's effectively the same thing in most circumstances.

Comment: Well, no, really, it's not.  If you never change the value of the variable to reference another object (just like if you never change a value type to be another value) the it doesn't matter if you close over the variable or the value.  Unless the variable is read only (or at least not changed between the creation of the closure and when it's invoked) there's a difference.  Additionally, this is dealing with a value type, not a reference type.

Answer (score 0):

In essence what is happening is that the compiler is declaring your `int i` outside of the loop and thus is not creating a new value of it for each action, just referencing the same one each time. By the time you execute the code i is 10 and so it prints 10 a lot.