# Why does setting a WPF ListCollectionView Filter predicate inside a for loop cause strange behavior?

Tags: c#, wpf, lambda, closures

I recently zeroed in on a problem I had with a WPF app, setting a Filter predicate in a for loop resulted in nothing appearing in the UI:

```
    private void SetListCollectionViewFiltersHasProblem()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; ++i)
        {
            _peopleViews[i].Filter = obj => ((Person)obj).Number == i;
        }
    }
```

whereas what I think of as equivalent code works just fine:

```
    private void SetListCollectionViewFiltersWorks()
    {
        _peopleViews[0].Filter = obj => ((Person)obj).Number == 0;
        _peopleViews[1].Filter = obj => ((Person)obj).Number == 1;
    }
```

It has something to do with the lambda expression in a For loop.  [This sort of problem exists in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) but I thought C# was different.

What's the best solution to using a For loop to set a Filter function without problems?

Full code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfListCollectionView.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Name="AddList0" Click="AddList0_Click">
            Add to list 0
        </Button>
        <Button Name="AddList1" Click="AddList1_Click">
            Add to list 1
        </Button>
        <ItemsControl Name="_list0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl Name="_list1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

namespace WpfListCollectionView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class Person
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public int Number { get; set; }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Person> _people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        private ListCollectionView[] _peopleViews = new ListCollectionView[2];        


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _peopleViews[0] = new ListCollectionView(this._people);
            _peopleViews[1] = new ListCollectionView(this._people);

            SetListCollectionViewFiltersHasProblem();
            //SetListCollectionViewFiltersWorks();

            // Set up the DataContexts
            _list0.DataContext = _peopleViews[0];
            _list1.DataContext = _peopleViews[1];

            // Put some data in
            _people.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Mike", Number = 0 });
            _people.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Joe", Number = 1 });
        }

        private void SetListCollectionViewFiltersHasProblem()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 1; ++i)
            {
                _peopleViews[i].Filter = obj => ((Person)obj).Number == i;
            }
        }

        private void SetListCollectionViewFiltersWorks()
        {
            _peopleViews[0].Filter = obj => ((Person)obj).Number == 0;
            _peopleViews[1].Filter = obj => ((Person)obj).Number == 1;
        }

        private void AddList0_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "AddedAlan", Number = 0 });
        }

        private void AddList1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "AddedAdam", Number = 1 });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set delegate which will be called later against each item of your collection. It's not called at this point and the problem is that it captures *i* variable not its value. You can work round it by using local variable inside your loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 1; ++i)
{
    var localValue = i;
    _peopleViews[i].Filter = obj => ((Person)obj).Number == localValue;
}
```

Comment: This works, but can you help me understand - isn't "i" an integer primitive and thus would be captured as a simple value in the lambda? (not a variable that changes?)

Comment: You are correct that it's value type but even for value types it does not store the value. If you will it stores pointer to _i_ and will take current value of _i_ at the time of execution. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861560/lambda-variable-capture-in-loop-what-happens-here) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/matthew%20manela/)