# Parameter of a method nested in a lambda expression changing when invoked

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following, which runs at the initialization of a node graph system for every ports of a node;

```
    private void Initialize()
    {
        // stats.Length return 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < stats.Length; i++)
            stats[i].Initialize(this, () => GetStats(i));
    }

    private void GetStats(int index)
    {
        // Issue; index returns 3
    }
```

If I print the `i` in the for loop, I get `0, 1, 2` as expected when I have 3 items.

Somehow, if I print `index` in `GetStats`, I get `3`.

I'm just at lost here, how is a value-type parameter in a method nested in a lambda can change value? Am I doing something stupid?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12861560/5311735

Comment: @Evk That's so counter-intuitive to how value-type behave...

Comment: Suppose you have a class A with integer field B. If you pass A to 100 functions and then change B - all 100 functions will see changed value, even if B is value-type. About the same story is here.

Comment: @Evk True, but in this case I'm not passing a member, I'm passing a value-type created on the stack. So how are 100 functions referencing a value from the stack that is long gone? Obviously, it has to be boxed in the delegate created. So how is at the moment of the boxing the value-type not being copied?

Comment: It's lifetime is extended, because compiler will rewrite the whole thing about as I described in a comment. So it will generate a class with int member, create instance of that class and your "i" is not on the stack any more - it's a field in that compiler-generated class. That's all because "i" is captured by your lambda and it's lifetime is not restricted by method boundary any more.