# Can someone explain to me why this does not work?

Tags: c#, memory, methods

I've been looking at this piece of code. I realize that the reason why this will always throw the notsupportedexception is because temp is always equal to 20; however, I'd like someone to explain to me why temp is always equal to 20 and not the value that was set to temp in the loop.

```
{
    delegate int Del(int i);
    static event Del MyEvent;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            MyEvent += a =>
            {
                int temp = i;
                if (a != temp) throw new NotSupportedException();
                return a * 2;

            };

        Console.WriteLine("C'est fini");
        Console.WriteLine(GetValue(5));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int GetValue(int arg)
    {
        foreach(Del myEvent in MyEvent.GetInvocationList())
        {
            try
            {
                return myEvent(arg);
            }
            catch(NotSupportedException)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because of closures and it's already answered very well here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438307/detailed-explanation-of-variable-capture-in-closures

Comment: is it because a is always not equal to i so it is throwing the exception and not making it to the return statement?

Comment: @BenCr Thanks! I didn't know what it was called and I apologize for the duplicate. I'm reading the question you linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is being used in a closure. You have this loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        MyEvent += a =>
            {
                int temp = i;
                if (a != temp) throw new NotSupportedException();
                return a * 2;
            };
```

The lambda uses `i`, not *the value of i*. In other words, you're creating delegates here that actually refer to the variable i *that is being changed by the loop*. One simple way around this is to use a local variable to force the closure to capture a variable that isn't being modified:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var value = i;
        MyEvent += a =>
            {
                int temp = value;
                if (a != temp) throw new NotSupportedException();
                return a * 2;
            };
    }
```

At first glance, you might think this doesn't work around your issue. But the local variable `value` is actually a different variable for each iteration. When that variable is captured in the closure, it won't be updated by the loop.

Answer (score 5):

In your handler definition you are closing over the loop variable `i`, not the current value of `i`, so when you reach the end of the loop, `i = 20` in all the registered handlers. You can fix it by copying `i` to another loop variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    int temp = i;
    MyEvent += a =>
    {
        if (a != temp) throw new NotSupportedException();
        return a * 2;
    };
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can change this behavior to use the value of i at the time the delegate is subscribed to the event?

Comment: @Aelphaeis - Yes, copy the current value inside the loop. See update.

Answer (score 1):

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        MyEvent += a =>
        {
            int temp = i;
            if (a != temp) throw new NotSupportedException();
            return a * 2;

        };
```

> I'd like someone to explain to me why temp is always equal to 20 and not *the value that was set to temp in the loop*.

The thing is, `temp` is not being set to anything **in** the loop. What you're doing is declaring a new anonymous method (using the `args => {}` syntax, or lambda expressions).

Your `MyEvent` delegate then aggregates pointers to all your 20 new anonymous methods.

These 20 methods won't be executed until you fire the event, which happens on this line:

```
return myEvent(arg);
```

By that time, `i` is 20. So `temp` will also be 20.

Answer (score 1):

Simply move `temp` outside of the closure.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    int temp = i;
    MyEvent += a =>
    {
        if (a != temp) throw new NotSupportedException();
        return a * 2;
    };
}
```