# Passing static values

Tags: c#

So I have some an int x I need to pass to another function, the problem is x changes before I use the function, so the value x changes to a different value than I want it. Is there a way to duplicate an integer (I couldn't find one)? That would solve my problem.

```
private void Init()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            Button tmpButton = new Button();
            tmpButton.Click += (sender, e) => ButtonClick(sender, e, x, y); 
            //x and y need to "freeze" their value at this point
        }
    }
}

private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e, int x, int y)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(x.ToString() + ":" y.ToString());
}
```

Output: "10:10"

Expected Output (if clicked on button 3,4): "3:4"

Comment: You could simply store the values in the Tag then retrieve them in the eventhandler.

Comment: Good idea, but how do I store two int values in a tag? I could convert the matrix to linear (Ex: 10*x + y), but I don't really want to have to convert it back.

Comment: As @JasonSec says, you need to put them in the `Tag` for each button. Either use a `Point` or some other custom `struct` to encapsulate them and put them in the tag as one thing.

Comment: I was thinking an array of int but Point works quite well for this situation nice suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a temporary variable:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
    {
        int tempX = x;
        int tempY = y;
        Button tmpButton = new Button();
        tmpButton.Click += (sender, e) => ButtonClick(sender, e, tempX, tempY); 
        //x and y need to "freeze" their value at this point
    }
}
```

You should always be careful when you are capturing variables in loops.

Basically, what happens is that your lambda is capturing the variables and *not* the value of the variables. So when the button is pressed, the loop is of course finished, and the value of the variables are 10.

Eric Lippert have written a [great series](http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/) on why this happens.

Comment: Oh yeah! For some reason I was thinking that I had to create a matrix for each temp. variable, when initializing the variable inside the matrix creates its own set. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

This is a closure problem and is solved by using a temp variable

```
int localX = x;
int localY = y;
```

To better understand captured variables, see [Jon Skeet's answer to this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438307/detailed-explanation-of-variable-capture-in-closures)