# How do lambdas scope to local variables?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, lambda

So my understanding of how the compiler handles lambdas is limited.

My understanding is that the compiler takes your lambda and turns it into a real method.

If that's the case then how does it scope to local variables?

```
    public async Task<dynamic> GetWebStuff()
    {
        dynamic ret = "";

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();          

        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += async (s, a) => 
        {
            ret = await Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(a.Result.ToString());
        };

        wc.DownloadString("http://www.MyJson.com");

        return ret;
    }
```

The above example will set the return value of ret to the caller which is a dynamic object of deserialized JSON.

How does that happen though if the compiler takes that completed event lambda and abstracts it into its own method? How does it know to set the ret value?

It's like me saying this (which obviously wont work)

```
        public async Task<dynamic> GetWebStuff()
        {
            dynamic ret = "";

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += wc_DownloadStringCompleted;            

            wc.DownloadString("google.com");

            return ret;
        }

        void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            ret = await Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(e.Result.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Check the answer by Jon Skeet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5438331/1803777

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does that creating an anonymous class. For example consider this code:

```
int x = 0;

Action action = () => x = 2;

action();

Console.Write(x);
```

And the generated class :

[image]

IL code of the `<Main>b__2` method which sets the value of `x`:

```
    .method assembly hidebysig instance void 
        '<Main>b__2'() cil managed
{
  // Code size       10 (0xa)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0002:  stfld      int32 ConsoleApplication1.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass0'::x
  IL_0007:  br.s       IL_0009
  IL_0009:  ret
} // end of method '<>c__DisplayClass0'::'<Main>b__2'
```

Comment: +1 It's correct that it's a closure, as per the other answer, but this is how they are actually implemented in C#

Comment: +1 for nice anwser, sorry for this question but what program did you use to see the internals, IL?

Comment: @FelipeOriani [ildasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 6):

I recommend not focusing on how the compiler does such a thing as that is an implementation detail that can change over time and as others have said different compiler implementations ([mono](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler)?).  Instead, know that such a thing happens because of [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29).

In Wiki:

> In programming languages, a closure (also lexical closure or function
>   closure) is a function or reference to a function together with a
>   referencing environment—a table storing a reference to each of the
>   non-local variables (also called free variables or upvalues) of that
>   function.[1](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler) A closure—unlike a plain function pointer—allows a
>   function to access those non-local variables even when invoked outside
>   its immediate lexical scope.

Comment: lol I am sorry but I could never accept this as an answer. If everyone just accepted that things just work and never ask why, then we would never have innovation.

Comment: I think if you understood closure you would not say that.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey didn't see the link. That's much better haha thanks

Comment: Also, different implementations of C# in different platforms could, theoretically, handle the specification in different ways.
Fundamentally, someone could implement the c# language in lisp. In this case, lambdas would be a first class citizen.

If you're interested in how the .NET compiler handle lambdas, I think it should be explicit in the question.

Answer (score 3):

So first off, *your code doesn't work*.  It doesn't work for reasons entirely unrelated to your question, but it doesn't work nonetheless.

The code does successfully mutate `ret` to be the result of the downloaded value, when the download actually completes.  Sadly, you have already returned a value *long* before that happens because you return the result of the task without waiting for the download to finish.

You'll notice that your implementation of `GetWebStuff` actually generates a compiler warning stating that "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously [...]".  Whenever you see this warning you can be virtually certain that your method is not designed properly, because it *appears* to be asynchronous while not actually doing anything asynchronously.

Here is a *valid* implementation of your method:

```
public Task<dynamic> GetWebStuff()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<dynamic>();

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();

    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += async (s, a) =>
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(await Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
            a.Result.ToString()));
    };

    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.MyJson.com"));

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Here the method returns a task that won't be completed until the event is fired, at which point the result of the task is set to be the result of the download.

As for how the closure works, it's easiest to simply see what the compiler transforms this code into:

```
class ClosureClass
{
    public TaskCompletionSource<dynamic> tcs;
    public async Task AnonymousMethod1(object s, 
        DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs a)
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(await Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
            a.Result.ToString()));
    }
}

public Task<dynamic> GetWebStuff()
{
    ClosureClass closure = new ClosureClass();
    closure.tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<dynamic>();

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();

    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += closure.AnonymousMethod1;

    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.MyJson.com"));

    return closure.tcs.Task;
}
```

When closing over a variable a new closure class is created, with an instance variable for each closed over variable.  The lambda is turned into an instance method that uses those instance fields.  The method that had the lambda creates an instance of that new type, uses its fields rather than locals wherever those closed over locals were used, and then uses the new named method where the lambda was.

Comment: Yea that code is completely broken. Another option would be to use `DownloadStringTaskAsync`.

Comment: I'm not sure why my comment got deleted. However, as I explained, this is not production code. It was an example not intended to be taken literal. It was just to demonstrate accessing local variables inside a lambda. Can we please focus on that.

Comment: @AMR you should also consider that if you are using async/await the compiler hoists locals in async methods in a similar fashion to lambdas. In fact, the compiler will hoist the locals even if they are not needed after any awaits. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx) for more details.