# Thread Safety and Task.Factory

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I'm quite new in parallel programing
i'd like to do some work with tasks
every task is initiated with param to do some simple work with id
but it seems the params all mixed up..

i'm sure i'm missing some key element in thread safety
can you help me understand what i'm doing wrong ?

i don't need any return value from the tasks, i just need them to finish their work.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int NumberOfTasks = 10;

    Task[] tasks = new Task[NumberOfTasks];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfTasks; i++)
    {
       tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSafeWork(i));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    Console.WriteLine("Done !");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void DoSafeWork(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("working on Task {0} ", i.ToString());
}
```

Current output (possible):

```
working on Task 3    
working on Task 6    
working on Task 10    
working on Task 10    
working on Task 10    
working on Task 10    
working on Task 10    
working on Task 10    
working on Task 10    
working on Task 10    
Done !
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - The foreach identifier and closures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512166/c-sharp-the-foreach-identifier-and-closures)

Comment: @Euphoric It's not, since the behavior differs between `foreach` and `for`

Comment: @l3arnon Yeah, it was fixed in newer C# version. But the problem is still same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that the loop variable is defined **outside** the loop. Note that the source of the problem is actually the closure and has nothing to do with threading.

Just create a local copy of your loop variable like this, so that the closure captures the copy:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfTasks; i++)
{
    var localCopy = i;
    tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSafeWork(localCopy));
}
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/512265/219187 for a detailed description.

Comment: that shouldn't be a problem while using value types like int32

Comment: @fubo That's a common assumption, but this is not true. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5438331/219187 for an in-depth explanation from Mr. Skeet himself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as theDmi said is that you are closing over the index and so all the tasks reference the same index while the `for` loop changes it.

While you could solve that by copying the current index value to a local variable a more elegant solution would be to use LINQ:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, NumberOfTasks).Select(i => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSafeWork(i)));
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Also, if you're not constrained to an older version of .Net you should be using `Task.Run`, `Task.WhenAll` and `await` instead:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, NumberOfTasks).Select(i => Task.Run(() => DoSafeWork(i)));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```