# Parameterised thread not holding all parameters of the method

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am calling a function using parameterised thread

```
ParameterizedThreadStart ts = delegate(object o) { ProcessDBThread(strDBName, dicMsg, objQueueItem.RunID); };
```

Hence the ts variable should logically contain all 3 parameters that I am passing, but it is only holding one parameter.

The above code is inside a loop hence the rest two parameter gets overridden by the latest value. As a result all the Parameterized Thread contains different `dicMsg` but same `strDBName`. In reality `strDBName` is different for every case.

I have checked the ts value in quick watch; `((System.Delegate)(ts)).Target`
Here the `Target` contains only one parameter, where it should have been three.

Just point me out where I might have been gone wrong!!

Comment: It would be awesome if you showed us all of the code. A [mcve] is worth a million bucks to us.

Comment: I understand your point of view but i am not able to post the whole code because its quite lengthy and not readable. Anyways your answer is working fine.

Comment: It's not a point of view, it's what is expected for a good question here on Stack Overflow. You should read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside your loop:

```
var dbn = strDBName;
var msg = dicMsg;
var rid = objQueueItem.RunID;
ParameterizedThreadStart ts = delegate (object o)
{
    ProcessDBThread(dbn, msg, rid);
};
```

---

When you have code like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ParameterizedThreadStart ts = delegate (object o) { Console.WriteLine(i); };
    ts.Invoke(null);
}
```

...the time it takes to start the threads is far longer than the time to take the `for` loop to finish so the value of `i` in the thread delegate becomes `10` before any of the threads start.

So by doing this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var j = i;
    ParameterizedThreadStart ts = delegate (object o) { Console.WriteLine(j); };
    ts.Invoke(null);
}
```

...you capture a copy of `i` in `j` and that doesn't change (because it is inside the loop's scope) so the parameters work correctly.

Comment: Its working but I am more inclined to know the need of doing this tweak?

Comment: @Abhijit_Srikumar You are running in to a [variable capture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438307/detailed-explanation-of-variable-capture-in-closures) issue.

Comment: @Abhijit_Srikumar - I've added an explanation. Had you provided your full code I would have given this explanation in the first instance.