# Should local variables be used in lambda statements when passed as delegates?

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

If I have a method that takes an argument of type `Action`, for example:

```
public void Foo(Action bar)
{
    bar?.Invoke();
}
```

And I wish to pass it a lambda that uses a local variable, e.g.:

```
private void SomeEvent(object sender, SomeEventArgs e)
{
    foo(() => { e.Cancel = true; });
}
```

Will this lambda execute as expected with respect to the use of the local variable, in this case, `e`? What I mean is, When `foo()` is called and in turn attempts to call the lambda, will it know `e`? Or will `e` be out of scope and I should do something like the following instead?

```
private void SomeEvent(object sender, SomeEventArgs e)
{
    foo((SomeEventArgs a) => { a.Cancel = true; }, e);
}

public void Foo(Action<SomEventArgs> bar, SomeEventArgs e)
{
    bar?.Invoke(e);
}
```

Comment: `e` would be accessible, the first example you showed didn't worked ?

Comment: Why ask us if something will work when you can simply run it for yourself?

Comment: It did work in my first test, but I am new to C# and using this as a class's public method so want to be sure I'm doing it correctly rather than relying on a fluke, so that it doesn't come back to haunt me later.

Comment: Yes, it should work as expected. This is called "captured variables". Read this post to understand better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438307/detailed-explanation-of-variable-capture-in-closures

Comment: @vyrp Variable capture, great! Thank you. Maybe you'd like to make that an answer?

Comment: I don't know... Normally they say to not just post a link as an answer.

Comment: @vyrp True. This directly answers my question though. Maybe you could answer with the link and a small explanation either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should work as expected. This is called "Variable capture", and is very well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438307/detailed-explanation-of-variable-capture-in-closures).

In your example, the `e` variable is captured, so it won't go out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

This little example shows that the local variable will be changed:

```
void Main()
{
    int local = 0;

    Foo(() => { local = 55; });
    Console.WriteLine(local);
}

public static void Foo(Action bar)
{
    bar?.Invoke();
}
```

Output:

> 55

This example can also be extended to include events:

```
public class P
{
    public delegate void MyEventDelegate(bool e);

    public event MyEventDelegate MyEvent;

    public void shootEvent() {MyEvent(false);}
}

void Main()
{       
    P p = new P();
    p.MyEvent += MyeventHandler;

    p.shootEvent();
}

public void MyeventHandler(bool b)
{
    Foo(() => { b = true; });
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

Output:

> true